# Kali Linux live

Tags: linux, windows

Как с загрузочной флешки с Kali Linux получить хеш от пароля на windows 10?

Comment: Вам на http://gramota.ru

Comment: @KoVadim, прям "не дови на меня".

Comment: например, найти. где win хранит хеш пароля в своём реестре (из его доков) и hivex'ом извлечь...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, дык он в SAM всегда хранился же.